# Access elements from an svg downloaded from url

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, svg

I want to access the elements from an svg downloaded from firebase URL. I set the data of the object to the URL (https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tangram-c997f.appspot.com/o/svgs%2F3.svg?alt=media&token=...), but the #document part is then empty. If the data is set to a local file, there will be the svg element in the #document.
[image]

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: host the document yourself, assuming you have the rights to do that. Browsers don't let you access the contents of documents from different domains.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this, could you elaborate on how to host the document yourself? (like a separate website for it?)

Comment: firebase hosting, i see. Thank you!

Comment: then that's where you'd need to put the svg file (or have that site/domain proxy the access so it looks like it's coming from that domain).

Comment: Oh does it mean uploading the svgs as part of the website? (like in public folder?)

Comment: that's one way to do it, assuming you're not violating the copyright or licence terms of the svg file.

Comment: i see, but there are lots of them, is there a better way you would recommend?

Comment: some kind of proxy. I'm not familiar with firebase though.

Comment: got it thank you so much!